# Angular Вывод уникальных значений

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="event in items">
    <li  ng-bind="toDate(event.date)">/</li>
    <li >
        <div>
            <div>
                <span ng-bind="toTime(event.date)">/</span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <span ng-if="event.name != 'null'">{{ event.name }}</span>
                {{ event.number }}
            </div>

            <div>
  <span ng-if="event.size> 0">
    <a href="#" ng-click="click(event.rid)">Download</a>
      {{event.size}}
  </span>

                <div>
                    <a href=""  ng-click="show = !show;load(event.rid)">Show images</a>
                    <span id="list_photo" ng-show="show"></span>
                </div>
                {{event.txt}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Сам контроллер:

```
$http.get('http://site.com/device/api/{{ imei.imei }}')
.then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.items = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function(err){console.log(err)})
```

В результате получаем массив с ответами:

```
{"date":"04.10.2017 18:34:04", "name":"ivan","number":"9208109010","size":"123","rid":"1236711","txt":"биография"}

`toDate(event.date)` возвращает `04.10.2017`. 
toTime(event.date) возвращает  18:34
```

Так вот, необходимо сгрупировать записи по датам.

```
04.10.2017
18:34  Ivan 9208109010 123 1236711 биография
11:34  Stepan 9108112010 321 127821 биография
05.10.2017
13:26  Mihail 9301421050 111 27373 биография
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать нужный фильтр средствами самого ангуляра:

```js
var app = angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('testCntr', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
        date: '03.10.2017',
        value: 1
      },
      {
        date: '03.10.2017',
        value: 2
      },
      {
        date: '04.10.2017',
        value: 3
      },
      {
        date: '04.10.2017',
        value: 4
      },
      {
        date: '04.10.2017',
        value: 5
      },
      {
        date: '05.10.2017',
        value: 6
      },
      {
        date: '05.10.2017',
        value: 7
      }
    ];

  }])
  .filter('uniqueDate', function() {
    return function(data) {
      return data.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
        if (!prev.find(function(item) {
            return item.date == cur.date;
          })) {
          prev.push(cur);
        }
        return prev;
      }, [])
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='testCntr'>
  <ul ng-repeat="d in data | uniqueDate">
    <li ng-bind="d.date">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Берем библиотеку [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy), а в частности функцию `uniqBy` и в контроллере пропускаем через нее ваш массив

```
$scope.uniqDates = lodash.uniqBy($scope.dates, 'date');
```

Потом их выводите как обычно

```
<ul ng-repeat="d in uniqDates">
  <li ng-bind="toDate(d.date)">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Поправлюсь, через d также выводится время каждой записи: toTime(d.date) без какой-либо фильтрации. + ещё пару полей: d.name, d.number. Затрудняюсь в таком случае применить Ваш метод

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов покажите тогда полностью что нужно вывести. По тому выводу что сейчас у вас в вопросе, мой ответ полностью соответствует.

Comment: Поправил в начале